# Removing duplicates in clojure

Tags: clojure

I have a sequence and trying to remove duplicates

```
case 1: 

(vec (into #{} [1 1 2 2 3 3])) ; => [1 2 3]


case 2:

(distinct [1 1 2 2 3 3]) ; => [1 2 3]
```

1. Both cases are bringing the results, so which one is better to use?
2. What's the difference between on those?

Comment: Someone please correct me if I'm wrong, but I think one big difference is that `distinct` will return a lazy sequence so can be efficiently used on very large (even infinite) collections.  `into` uses `reduce` underneath so would have to traverse the collection up front (I think).  Also `distinct` will maintain the order of its elements while `into` may jumble them. If none of that is an issue `distinct` certainly has the advantage of clearly saying what it's doing.

Comment: nitpicking: the set will jumble them (the into conj-es the values in).  also without the vec around, the resulting set can act as a function which later could be used. so for definition of "better" either use distinct for what's in the answer already or just go with the set (no vec).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As for differences, jas covered most of them in his comment:

1. `distinct` is lazy
2. `distinct` with no arguments is a transducer
3. `distinct` maintains order

As for which one is preferred, `distinct` is for the above reasons, but also because it explains what you need. I forget which Lisp book talked about this (might have been *Let Over Lambda*), but when given the choice between two similar functions, prefer the one that's more specific. `distinct` explains that you want distinct elements. `(into #{} xs)` might produce distinct values, but it also allows your intent to be misunderstood. Someone could easily think you wanted a set for some reason. `distinct` narrows down the *why*.